# Can Gravitational Waves Be Artificially Produced By An Electric Motor?

Tags: gravitational-waves

If gravitational waves are produced by two spinning black holes, is it possible to produce vacuum waves by mounting a giant dumbbell on a giant electric motor that can spin the dumbbell at a high speed (perhaps along two vectors) in a vacuum?  Would the vacuum waves produced (assuming they are produced) be distinguishable from gravitational waves?

Comment: I should further specify that the vacuum is deep space where there is virtually zero gravity.

Comment: Absolutely! ---  but you will be hard-put to detect them.

Comment: You can produce gravitational waves by waving your hand. They’ll be too weak to detect, but so will the ones from your giant dumbbell.

Comment: FWIW, the average power of the gravitational waves emitted by the Earth-Moon system is ~7.4 microwatts.

Comment: Everything is emitting gravitational waves all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I'm assuming if enough input power is used, the centripetal force will be sufficient to produce detectable waves.  Further, the input force could be any force that is more powerful than gravity.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 3):

Gravitational waves are radiated from changing mass quadrupole moments, $Q$, at the lowest order.

The power goes as:

$$ P \propto Q^2 \omega^6 $$

where $\omega$ is the appropriate angular frequency.

For rotating binaries or dumbbells:

$$ Q \propto MR^2 $$

so:

$$ P \propto M^2R^4\omega^6 $$

The good news is that GW detection is based on amplitude, not power, so the signal goes as:

$$ A \propto  M R^2 \omega^3 $$

You can certainly spin dumbbells at 10-100 Hz, maybe 1000 Hz, which either cancels, or buys you a factor of $10^3$, while $R$ is a foot vs maybe 50 miles?

So that's $10^{-9}$, so we're down by 1,000,000$\times$.

The black hole mass, 50x the sun, so your down by an additional $10^{-35}\times$ for a total of $10^{-44}$.

Now the only hope is range. Say the far field for the dumbbell is around ten feet ($10\,{\rm ns} \times c$)....we can compare that to one billion light years, for a positive factor of $3 \times 10^{16}$ for a total:

$$ A_{DB}/A_{BH} \approx 3 \times 10^{-28} $$

Recall LIGO detected a movement of $10^{-17}\,$m, iirc..., so we're at 50 billion times smaller than a Planck length.

And that is a resounding "No"....and LIGO doesn't work at 1000 Hz, anyway, so we may have to give up the frequency boost.

Caveat: I recall reading the classical LIGO wave corresponded to a graviton occupation number of around $10^{30}$, so that leaves a few hundred thousand gravitons to detect, but less than a Planck length of motion? Maybe check the numbers and report back?

Comment: Thanks for the lucid response!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a general formula for any force causing the dumbbell's centripetal acceleration or centripetal force:  h = (FR/mc^2)(na/r).  Where h is the unit-less strain, F is the centripetal force, R is the length of the dumbbell, m is the dumbell's mass, a = G(Planck mass)/c^2, n is a scaling factor (since the force used is most likely stronger than gravity), r is the distance to the observer.  The rod that joins the opposite weights should be strong enough to withstand the centripetal force, so, using Hook's equation: kR = F and k = F/R.  The input power (P) needed to increase F to a level where h is detectable is P >= FRf (assuming heat loss and friction) where f is frequency.  If all goes well, the waves produced can be represented with the D'Alembertian operator * h.